# Javascript change CSS class background image from AJAX if-loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have this CSS:

```
.modal-content {
    max-height: 370px;
    background-image: url('../images/img_before_submit.png');
}
```

And I am having a php-mail script that will respond with and "ok" for a successful mail sending or "bad" for an error.

I am using a AJAX script for mail handling:

```
              success:function(response) {

                      if(response == 'ok') { 
                        $('.modal-content').css('background-image', 'url(images/success.png)');
                        sleep(2000); 
                        alert(response);
                      } else {
                        $('.modal-content').css('background-image', 'url(images/error.png)')
                        sleep(2000); 
                        alert(response);
                      } 
}
```

From the console and outside the if-loop in the AJAX this code work as expected:

```
$('.modal-content').css('background-image', 'url(images/img.png)');
```

But inside the AJAX if-loop this code does not apply, but the correct alert msg response is coming through and is showing up! How can I set the background-image from within the if-loop?

Comment: First ifs are not loops, second when comparing strings in JavaScript use === not ==

Comment: in your css you have '../images(...)' but in javascript 'images(..)' it is not the  same path

Comment: Sorry for my ifs-are-not loops confusion.. I am still learning! Using === instead of == does not make any difference... I still get the correct "ok" or "bad". The path does not seem to be an issue.. I do get to set the correct  background-image when used outside the if-else statement

Comment: 1. Try putting a breakpoint and see whether it reaches inside any of the conditions.  2. if it does test what is `$('.modal-content')`. Still good? try changing the `.css('background-image' ` to `.css('backgroundImage'` Nothing works? Do you see any error in console?

Comment: 1. The code reaches the `alert(response);` and outputs the correct response ok/bad.. I think that shows that the actual if-else statement work! 2. I  tried changing the .css('background-image' to .css('backgroundImage'. Still nada! and there is no error in the console! Thanks for trying to help!